# How do I investigate a suspicious link?

Tags: malware, url, scan

I made a RuneScape account about a week ago. I stupidly responded to a scam by clicking on a link provided to me in the game. I think I may have a keylogger, which would explain why my new account was drained of all its items in the past 24 hours.

I hope someone has the expertise and resources to tell me how I can safely analyze this URL and determine if it's malicious or not.

[image: The link's URL is in this picture, obviously, so it is inert until you manually type it in]

Comment: *"I think I may have a keylogger, which would explain why my new account was drained of all its items in the past 24 hours. "* A [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) might be possible also but not sure how RuneScape  works and or if RuneScape is even prone to that.

Answer (score 1):

Defining what you mean by "malicious", what you mean by "investigate", and who is doing the investigating are all important.

If you need to determine if the site is hosting **malicious code**, then you need to run a malware scan on the URL. There are many online sites that can do this for you (as well as the AV on your machine). [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/url) is a big one and probably the most famous. It will give you an opinion that the average user can understand.

There are also **sandboxes** that you can set up that inspect what the code on the linked site does so that you can do an in-depth analysis on the site yourself. This is not for the average user.

**Phishing defense** sites, like [PhishTank](http://www.phishtank.com/), will help you look up to see if the site has phishing markers or if the link has been reported as a phishing site by the community.

There are also various **reputation ranking** sites and **URL blacklist** sites that allow you to look up how "dodgy" a site is based on its past behaviour.

For shortened URLs, you can use a **URL de-shortener** to find out where the link actually goes to then feed into the above.